# VBScriptでIEが閉じれません。

Tags: vbs

vbscriptにて、WEBでのパスワード認証画面が正常に動作するかのバグチェックをしようと思っております。

```
'シェルを起動する
Dim wsh
Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'IEを起動する
Dim ie
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

'IEをアクティブにする
Dim wLoc, wSvc, wEnu, wIns
Set wLoc = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set wSvc = wLoc.ConnectServer
Set wEnu = wSvc.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
Dim pId
For Each wIns in wEnu
If Not IsEmpty(wIns.ProcessId) And wIns.Description = "iexplore.exe" Then
    pId = wIns.ProcessId
End If
Next
Set wLoc = Nothing
Set wEnu = Nothing
Set wSvc = Nothing
While not wsh.AppActivate(pId) 
    Wscript.Sleep 100 
Wend 

'IEで指定URLを開く
ie.Navigate "http://〜"
Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4
Loop

Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'IEで要素に値を入れる
Dim elm 
Set elm = ie.document.getElementById("logincode")
elm.Value = "000000"
Set elm = ie.document.getElementById("password")
elm.Value = "000000"
Set elm = ie.document.getElementById("loginbutton")
elm.Click

For Each ie In objShell.Windows()
    If InStr(LCase(ie.FullName), "iexplore.exe") Then
        WScript.Echo ie.LocationURL
    End If
Next

WScript.Sleep 3000
ie.Quit
```

まだ処理を書いていないですが、ループ処理でパスワードを一つずつ試して行き、
パスワード確認画面を突破できた場合と出来なかった場合は、その時のURLの違いで判断する予定です

しかしその処理を追加する前に、一番最後の行の
ie.Quitの部分でエラーが発生してしまい、先に進めません。

発生しているエラーは以下です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

確認するパスワードは1000個ぐらいあるので自動化で行いたいです。
おわかりになる方がいらしたら、お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の処理で`ie`を書き換えているからです。

```
For Each ie In objShell.Windows()
    If InStr(LCase(ie.FullName), "iexplore.exe") Then
        WScript.Echo ie.LocationURL
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `For Each objIE In objShell.Windows()
        If InStr(LCase(objIE.FullName), "iexplore.exe") Then
            WScript.Echo objIE.LocationURL
        End If
    Next

    WScript.Sleep 3000
    ie.Quit`
書き換えて実行してみました、エラーは発生しなくなりましたが、IEは閉じません、
別のエラーが発生しているというわけでもなく、原因がわからないので教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `ie.Quit`
を使用するのをあきらめて、
`Set Locator = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set Service = Locator.ConnectServer
Set oProcs = Service.ExecQuery _
("Select * From Win32_Process Where Description=""iexplore.exe""")
For Each oProc In oProcs
oProc.Terminate
Next`
こちらの書き方を使用することで閉じることができました。
お騒がせしました。